# How to install two different versions of Minecraft Forge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My child has a Minecraft installation and wants to play two mods:

1. Lucky Blocks
2. Orespawn

Currently, there is a profile,

- which runs under Minecraft version 1.8 and
- uses Forge 11.14.3.1450.

I installed *Lucky Blocks* and it worked.

But Orespawn [requires](http://www.orespawn.com/download-17.html) Minecraft 1.7.10 and Forge 10.13.2.1230.

How can I install a second Forge for Orespawn, without compromising the already installed Forge for Lucky Blocks?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade @Dmitri, but we don't support modded Minecraft support. But since it's not a crash log (like the other ones, if you haven't already noticed), I'll have a crack at it for you.

Comment: MultiMC is a launcher created with this specific purpose in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question: **No, you can't have two versions of Forge installed over the same Minecraft installation, and neither can you have a mod compiled for a future/previous version of Forge run alongside those that has been compiled for said version.**

## So why?

Forge in itself, is a modification to the entire coding of Minecraft, allowing players to inject new code (hence mods) easily.
But because the structure of Minecraft's internal settings change from update to update, many methods get depreciated or moved (means things get messy).

That's why mods compiled for a release of Minecraft cannot run on another one.

---

## So, what's the solution?

To simply put it, **downgrade**. Until there is an update to the mods (in this case, OreSpawn), that is your only option.

Seeing that you're trying to use Orespawn and Lucky Blocks, and that *both* mods have a 1.7.10 version, your best option is to downgrade back to 1.7.10 and install their respective versions of the mod for it.

As for missing features, you simply have to put up with it, since it's not possible to have a newer version of a mod run on an older version of Minecraft.

Minecraft Forge for 1.7.10 - [Minecraft Forge](http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/index_1.7.10.html)
Orespawn for 1.7.10 - [Original Website](http://www.orespawn.com/download-17.html) | [Direct Download Link](http://www.weebly.com/uploads/2/5/3/5/25358181/orespawn-1.7.10-20.3.zip)
Lucky Blocks Mod for 1.7.10 - [Original Website](http://www.minecraftascending.com/projects/lucky_block/lucky_block.html) | [Direct Download Link](http://www.minecraftascending.com/projects/lucky_block/download/version/files/kTFCmVjS/5-1-0/%5B1-7-10%5D_Lucky_Block_v5-1-0.jar)

---

**Note:** When I say 'version/release of forge', I don't mean each individual build, but the targeted Minecraft version for them.

Seeing that you're proficient in Java on StackOverflow, you could (if the mods are open-sourced and you have knowledge in Minecraft modding) attempt to port the older version of the mod and make it (OreSpawn) compatible with 1.8's release(s) of Forge allowing you to utilize the newer version of Lucky Blocks and its new features (if any).

Comment: can't you install Minecraft in 2 different directories since 1.6? I haven't played minecraft in so long so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @Jaketr00 You can, but he's trying to *merge* two different releases of Minecraft, not run two different installs of Minecraft.

Answer (score -4):

Use twitch, it alows u to use various amounts of profiles for minecraft with diffrent verisons.

Comment: I assume you mean the Twitch App, and it doesn't specify you can use it for multiple accounts and/or/ installations.

Comment: When you say you can use Twitch, do you mean using the Twitch desktop app to run multiple profiles? The reason I'm asking this is because if it's for @Dimitri's child, then it would be violating the Terms Of Service for the child to use Twitch. Hope this helps!